# Creating text effects like curved, arched, wedged in ruby on rails or php

Tags: php, ruby, image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick

i know there is a convert -swirl effect in imagemagick but can i create other effects for text like curved, arched, wedged, pinched etc.. just like wordart in word.

i am open to other packages that might help me get this thing done.. php or ruby..

Comment: I decided to use the mini_magick with ror and use the examples here 
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/texteffect/index.php

and here 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

to figure out a few parameters to get the effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/texteffect/index.php
If you are interested, you can run this shell script through php [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function or any other language which provide you with such an ability.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/), which is a Ruby interface to the ImageMagick library.

There are interfaces for many other languages as well, including PHP.
Look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars suggested, RMagick is a good choice for doing it in RoR.  If you're looking in PHP, I'm not sure that it can do some of the things you're wanting to, but GD2 (which is usually natively included with PHP if you installed PHP with a package manager) is a good tool.  There is also a PHP extension for ImageMagick.